# `less` "search backward" command line switch?

Tags: less

I know `less +/pattern filename` will open the file and navigate to the first occurrence of the pattern. Is there a way to tell `less` to search from the end backwards? Does it even accept more than one `+` switch?

Do not work:

```
less +?pattern filename
less +G +?pattern filename
```

Answer (score 15):

The `man` page for `less` states the syntax is `less +?pattern filename`

```
?pattern
       Search  backward  in  the  file for the N-th line containing the
       pattern.  The search starts at the last line displayed (but  see
       the -a and -j options, which change this).
```

Press `n` to continue to search for the pattern backwards. Press `N` to search for the pattern forwards.

**Example**

For *testfile.txt* of

```
apple
banana
carrot
apple
banana
carrot
apple
banana
carrot
```

`less +?banana testfile.txt` shows the following:

```
banana
carrot
```

Comment: The man page does not state so explicitly, and the syntax you provided does not lead to the desired result. It works, in a sense that the same thing happens as if you were to open the file and try searching backwards - you get "Pattern not found". Backward search does not jump to the end of the file when you are on the first line of the file. Hence, I tried `less +G +?pattern filename`, but then again, reading the `man` page, it appears that only one `+cmd` is allowed. So, it appears that there is no way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do. Can you provide an example? The syntax I provided above looks for a term starting at the last line of the file and searches upwards.

Comment: Try `less +/cd .bash_history` vs. `less +?cd .bash_history`. The first example opens the file and navigates to the first occurrence of `cd` in your bash history (hopefully you have them). The second example does nothing, except open the file, as if it's `less .bash_history`.

Comment: `less +?cd .bash_history` on my system shows the latest occurrence of `cd` in my bash history. Perhaps you have the `LESS` environmental variable set in a way that is overriding what I'm expecting?

Comment: It does nothing on mine. `$LESS` is not set.

Comment: Got it. Something to do with bash expansion probably. It works when the command is quoted: `less +'?cd' .bash_history`.

Comment: @Garen , `?pattern` means that the file is searched in the backward direction. So then lowercase n continues the search in the backward direction, and uppercase N searches in the reverse direction of backwards (the forward direction).

Comment: @davidmneedham I somehow missed that, deleting my comment to reduce noise.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is better to escape `?` and the `pattern` from the shell like this:

```
less '+?pattern' filename
```

In your case you might not get what you expect when e.g. there is a file matching `+?pattern` or you have set bash option `nullglob` (use `shopt nullglob` to check it).

In doubt, you can use `echo` to look what your shell changed:

```
echo less +?pattern filename
```